# .hide() and .show() not caching properly CSS's display property

Tags: jquery, css

*Note: I've found the causant of my problem. See below for more info.*

I'll be concise. Here's my scenario:

The HTML file:

```
<form id="login">
<label for="editable">i'm a label for editable</label>
<input id="editable" type="text" />
</form>
```

The CSS file:

```
#login label { display: block }
```

The JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login label').hide().show();
});
```

The desired behavior is to show the element again with the same CSS properties (`display: block`), but in the DOM it seems that the `label` element gets another (maybe the default?) ones (in this case, `display: inline`). *Note: I've checked the HTML and CSS files. Everything is correct. The problem is in the javascript file.*

Seen on jQuery's API docs, concerning `.hide()` method:

> With no parameters, the .hide() method is the simplest way to hide an element:
>
> $('.target').hide();
>
> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that **the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored** to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Seen on jQuery's API docs, concerning `.show()` method:

> With no parameters, the .show() method is the simplest way to display an element:
>
> $('.target').show();
>
> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that **the display property is restored to whatever it was initially**. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Am I missing something? I'm wrong? Or is just a not desired behavior?

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

Include the CSS first, then the JS later.

Comment: It behaves correctly for me in Safari and Chrome. The display is restored to block. Which browser is giving you trouble? And which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Is your CSS loaded before the jQuery runs? I'm using the same version of Chrome as you, and it's fine.

Comment: I'm using latest minified version (1.4.3). Chrome 7 (latest stable) for OSX. The CSS is linked is in the head (it also `@import` s the `html5reset.css` file, but it doesn't alter label in this case...), and the script is located before the `</head>` closing tag.

Comment: As a sanity check, have you tried without the `html5reset.css`?

Comment: One more sanity check. Alert the display property on the next line: `alert($('#login label').css('display'));`

Comment: I think I've found the solution! I was using Google Fonts importing them to CSS with the command `@import`. I don't really know why but commenting the lines concerning Google Fonts inclusion, it made my label displaying correctly again.

Comment: @frarees - Glad you found the culprit. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the CSS first, then the JS later.

Answer (score 1):

`hide()` and `show()` do not change the properties on an element's CSS class.

Put `display:none` as an **inline** style of anything you want hidden by default. Do not put it in the CSS class and everything will work fine.

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the values from CSS? Do I have to inline them on HTML? (I really want to take the CSS and the HTML as splited as possible)

Comment: How would that make it display `block` instead of its natural `inline` when showing?

Comment: You put that in its CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in FF3.6, IE8, Safari5, Chrome and OPERA10

Here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kjwxu/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/kjwxu/

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login label').hide().show("fast", function() {$(this).attr("display", "block")});
});
```

Also of note if you dont like the flicker then you can remove "fast" and replace with 1 (meaning 1 millisecond)

Here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kjwxu/3/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/kjwxu/3/

Comment: Same. I tried on Chrome and simulate it on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/usetu3). All works correctly.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 7 for OSX (latest stable release) on a local server, and for me doesn't work.

Comment: @frarees..  I provided a possibility and potential work around.  I do not run MacOSX and cannot test, but this should work.

Comment: thanks for your workaround. In fact, I used to solve this with `.css('display','block')`, chaining it to the `.show()` function. It solved the problem, but I would like to do it without explicitally defining the style inside the script but retrieving it from the styles defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're having this issue, but a workaround would be to add a class in order to style it.

CSS

```
#login label { display: block }
#login label.hidden { display: none }
```

JS

```
$('#login label').addClass('hidden').removeClass('hidden');
```

---

**EDIT:** Seems from our discussion in the comments, that commenting out the additional CSS imports fixed the issue.

Comment: @frarees - Commenting here since instead of your new question since they are related. What happens if you give your code a short delay? Like `setTimeout(function() { $('#login label').hide().show(); }, 200);` Does that cause it to work properly?

Comment: @frarees - Also, I assume that it displays correctly when there isn't any jQuery. Is that right?